# Can I use Create React App Jest Testing with a test reporter without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, test-reporting

I would like to output the results of my jest testing to a file format like [JUnit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-junit) without ejecting from react-scripts.

By using the `--json` command I can output it to JSON but I was hoping to get a format that Jenkins can process by default.

I cant seem to find if this is supported and I don't want to eject from Create React App, is there another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything fancy.  Just install `jest-junit` and then run with the additional `reporters` flag:

```
yarn test --reporters=jest-junit
```

You can also add it to the [`jest` settings of `package.json`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration).  Probably something like this:

```
{
  "name": "your-package",
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": ["jest-junit"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the cli option `--reporters=jest-junit` worked because this isnt a `coverageReporter` the `package.json` change wont work and the `reporters` key isnt valid in Create React App

Comment: `npm test -- --reporters=jest-junit` is the npm version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with `npm` and the `jest-teamcity` reporter by modifying the package.json file.

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom --reporters=jest-teamcity",
    ...
  },
...
}
```